# Value of option

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, select

I can't get the whole value of my select box.

In my script:

```
$company = $("#company").val();
```

In my HTML:

```
<select id='company' name='company'>
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "project") or die("error" . mysql_error($con));
    $qry = "SELECT * FROM company";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $qry);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<option value=" . $row['company_name'] . ">" . $row['company_name'] . "</option>";
    }
?>
</select>
```

`$company` has only the first word.

Comment: What you are getting it right now..

Comment: can't recreate the problem - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jfpthqc3/1/

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem http://jsfiddle.net/grLh7ryk/

Comment: i already updated my question...

Comment: both options are same what do you expect.

Comment: `mysqli_connect` + `mysql_error`... erm, which of the two extensions _are_ you really using? I hope it's not `mysql` (which is deprecated). Either way, `mysql_error` is wrong here

Answer (score 2):

Try to put single quote after value like

```
echo"<option value='".$row['company_name']. "'>" .$row['company_name']. "</option>";
                  ^^^                       ^^^
```

Comment: Nice catch, especially if the company has a space in its name.

Answer (score 0):

try this.change your jquery like this and option tag line

```
    $( "#company option:selected" ).text();

    <select id='company' name='company'>
    <?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","project") or die("error" . mysql_error($con));
    $qry="SELECT * FROM company";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$qry);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
     echo"<option value='".$row['company_name']. "'>" .$row['company_name']. "</option>";
    }
      ?>
     </select>
```